# Правильность ip - адреса 172.17.255.1

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Ситуация такая: У меня есть задание от преподавателя. Нужно настроить статическую маршрутизацию (смотреть на схему ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть задания в том, чтобы пинговались компьютеры с сервером.

Я настроил на маршрутизаторах маршрут от сервера до компьютеров (то есть до сети `10.0.0.0`), то есть пакет долетает до компьютеров (проверил на встроенном симуляторе Cisco Packet Tracer), но обратно ответа не приходит, потому что не настроен маршрут обратно до сервера (то есть до сети `172.17.255.0`).

Проблема в том, что маршрутизаторы не дают мне настроить маршрут до сети `172.17.255.0`, выдают ошибку: `Inconsistent address and mask`.

Я подозреваю, что проблема именно в октете `255` в ip - адресе.

Может ли такой октет как `255` в ip - адресе влиять на работу маршрутизации? При этом маршрутизатор `r4` и `local server` пингуются друг с другом и проблем никаких нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последний единичный бит в адресе сети `172.17.255.0` - 24-й. Т.е. `172.17.255.0` может иметь маску /24 или мельче. Указанная на рисунке маска /16 - недопустима.

Если адрес - `172.17.255.132`, а маска /16, то для получения адреса сети надо обнулить все биты после 16-го (т.е. последние два октета). Получится адрес сети - `172.17.0.0 / 16`.

Comment: Сделал вывод из вашего ответа. Настроил маршруты на маршрутизаторах с помощью команды: ```ip route 172.17.0.0 255.255.0.0 ...```. Как вы и написали, убрал два последних октета. Все заработало. Спасибо!